# Vs Code does not show flutter quick documentations while typing code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, code-documentation

When I started with it, I used to get these quick docs where it would for example explain what the class would do or show the different color shades alongwith their numbers but now it doesnt and Ive tried every solution on the internet but got no outcomes.